# possible to generate RxDB schema from existing graphql schema?

Tags: rxdb

Curious if this is possible, I see `graphQLSchemaFromRxSchema` for working in the other direction, but we already have a graphQL schema we want to use.

Comment: did you find an answer to this?

Comment: not yet, we still haven't had time to start our transition!